# Change Leaflet Map Zoom control style using Drupal Leaflet module

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7, leaflet, ip-geolocation

I am unable to find settings where I can make Zoom Control Style "Large" for Leaflet map.

**Current system**
My Page is coming from View, where view format is "Map (Leaflet API, via IPGV&M)". I am displaying custom markup on map using Leaflet marker.
I am using following modules for D7

- Leaflet
- Leaflet views
- Leaflet More Maps
- ip_geoloc

**Edited**

I need to change Zoom control style from Small to Large. This is a small Zoom control:[image] prntscr.com/9eeq41 and This is a Large [image] prntscr.com/9eeqqu

Comment: Leaflet is a completely different library than Google Maps. Unsure as to why you are trying to use Google Maps logic on a Leaflet map. That will never work. Please edit your question and elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by including Zoomslider JS and CSS in your theme's js and css folder respectively.

Bind it with leaflet.map and then add zoomslider control to map.

Your code should look something like this :

```js
jQuery(document).bind('leaflet.map', function(event, map, lMap) {
    L.control.zoomslider().addTo(lMap);
});
```

This will add zoomslider control to your map.

You can find Reference here : [Leaflet Zoomslider](http://kartena.github.io/Leaflet.zoomslider/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE/display.
2. At Geofield (field) format choose leaflet and click the settings
   icon on the right.

There you can change min/max view settings like in the pic.[image]

Comment: I dont want settings for Zoom. I want Zoom control small to Large.

Comment: I mean to say, I need to change Zoom control style from Small to Large. This is a small Zoom control: http://prntscr.com/9eeq41 and This is a Large http://prntscr.com/9eeqqu